# How to determine where a face (as it appears on the screen) is defined?

Tags: faces, fonts

I very much dislike the font faces I get for some modes.  I know that I can customize them, but in some cases (e.g. `org-mode`) this would require customizing dozens of faces.

Therefore, what I really want to determine is, for a given character, *where* is its face, ***as it appears on the screen***, defined?  I'm hoping that this would lead me to a more efficient and maintainable way to fix the problem.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of an approach that does *not* get me what I'm after: determine the name of a character's face (e.g. through `M-x describe-char`), and then invoke `describe-face` to see where the face is defined (supposedly).

When I do this I often arrive at definitions that are entirely at odds with what I see on the screen.  This is why the question title emphasizes *as it appears on the screen*.

For example, if I invoke `M-x describe-char` when point is at an oversized [orange](http://www.colorhexa.com/cb4b16.png) character in my current buffer, the output I get tells me that its face is `org-level-1`.  (FWIW, I get exactly the same result if I use `M-: (get-char-property (point) 'face)` or `C-u C-x =` instead.)

Now, the output of `M-x describe-face` for this face (`org-level-1`) includes the following:

```
Defined in `org-faces.el'.

           Family: Monaco
          Foundry: unspecified
            Width: unspecified
           Height: 1.3
           Weight: unspecified
            Slant: unspecified
       Foreground: #cb4b16
DistantForeground: unspecified
       Background: unspecified
        Underline: unspecified
         Overline: unspecified
   Strike-through: unspecified
              Box: unspecified
          Inverse: unspecified
          Stipple: unspecified
             Font: unspecified
          Fontset: unspecified
          Inherit: variable-pitch
```

This face specification, as far as it goes, pretty much matches what I see on the screen (though I don't know what `variable-pitch` means when applied to a fixed-width font like Monaco).

But if I follow the reference to `org-faces.el`, I find this

```
(defface org-level-1 ;; originally copied from font-lock-function-name-face
  (org-compatible-face 'outline-1
    '((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) (:foreground "Blue1"))
      (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark)) (:foreground "LightSkyBlue"))
      (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) (:foreground "Blue"))
      (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark)) (:foreground "LightSkyBlue"))
      (((class color) (min-colors 8)) (:foreground "blue" :bold t))
      (t (:bold t))))
  "Face used for level 1 headlines."
  :group 'org-faces)
```

Note that this definition bears little relation to the specification listed by `describe-face`.  In particular, all the colors it mentions are shades of blue, nothing remotely like the color [#cb4b16](http://www.colorhexa.com/cb4b16.png) reported by `describe-face`.  In addition, it says nothing about any of the other spec items (Family, Height, Inherit) given explicit values in the output of `describe-face`.

This is why I emphasize that I'm not looking for the location of some "theoretical"/"nominal" definition of a named face, but the actual definition of the face that I'm seeing on the screen.

**EDIT 2:**

Digging deeper into the results described above, if I evaluate the following sub-expression in the definition of `org-level-1`

```
(org-compatible-face 'outline-1
    '((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) (:foreground "Blue1"))
      (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark)) (:foreground "LightSkyBlue"))
      (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) (:foreground "Blue"))
      (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark)) (:foreground "LightSkyBlue"))
      (((class color) (min-colors 8)) (:foreground "blue" :bold t))
      (t (:bold t))))
```

I get this

```
((t :inherit outline-1))
```

So I repeat the same wild-goose-chase with `outline-1` in place of `org-level-1`.  I find that it is defined in `outline.el`, as follows:

```
(defface outline-1
  '((t :inherit font-lock-function-name-face))
  "Level 1."
  :group 'outlines)
```

So, one more time, now with `font-lock-function-name-face`, defined in `font-lock.el`:

```
(defface font-lock-function-name-face
  '((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) :foreground "Blue1")
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))  :foreground "LightSkyBlue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) :foreground "Blue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))  :foreground "LightSkyBlue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8)) :foreground "blue" :weight bold)
    (t :inverse-video t :weight bold))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight function names."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)
```

This seems to be the end of this tedious line, but the final definition is no closer to what I see on the screen.

Comment: Using `ido`, when I choose a command like `make-face-bold`, the first (default) completion is the face at the point.

Comment: `M-x describe-face` describes the current properties of the face. These can be adjusted by lots of factors, the most obvious one being your currently loaded theme (as seen with `F1 v custom-enabled-themes`).  What you have traced are definitions that make up most of their properties, but don't contain these other factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, the actual properties of a face is determined by a function called `face-spec-recalc`. It is based in the values of the symbol properties `theme-face` and `face-override-spec`. The former contains a list of all themes that you have applied that contribute to the face. (I'm not 100% what the latter does, but I think it contains user overrides.)

This function updates the actual face information of a frame.

In my project [e2ansi](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi) (a package that renders font-lock buffers using ANSI sequences that provide syntax highlighting support for `less`), I reversed-engineered this so I can play the "what if" game (e.g. assuming that I have 16 colors and a dark background, what attributes would a face be given).

I guess that you could modify it so that it also would record the theme that provided each attributes.

Comment: I think your answer is probably the closest I'm going to get to what I'm after.  Thanks.  (BTW, very cool stuff in your repo.)

Answer (score 3):

Do you really care *where* the face was (last) defined? (Why?)

I'm guessing that what you really want to know is *what* the current face definition is - each of the attributes.

For that, use `C-u C-x =` in front of a character that has the face you want to know about.

Or just use `list-faces-display` and compare appearances (if the appearance is not too common).

It is also the case often that once you know the name of the face you can find out where it is defined, if you really are interested in that. You can use `M-x describe-face` to find out where it was defined originally, at least.

Comment: Note that after `C-x C-x =` you can either move point to a face name and use `M-x find-face-definition`, or simply follow the built-in links -- the face name links to the `describe-face` screen, and from there (as Drew indicates) you get a link to the file (and line) which defined it.

Comment: @phils Surely you meant `C-u C-x =`?

Comment: Please see my EDIT.  (BTW, regarding the question at the beginning of your answer: please grant posters the courtesy of assuming that they mean what they write.  To do otherwise is not only rude, but also a waste of your time and everybody else's.)

Comment: +1 for what @wasamasa said in a comment. Which is why I asked whether (and why) you really want to know *where* the current appearance was set. In the general case, that is problematic: the face *can be changed anywhere*, whether via user customizations or on-the-fly code. There is really no way to know what last changed the face. This is similar to asking what last set a given variable's value. And no, no disrespect or rudeness was intended (or expressed, IMHO). We are trying to help you, not waste your time. You waste your own time (IMHO), if you try to find what last changed a face.

Comment: Harald Hanche-Olsen: Thanks, yes, that's exactly what I meant. I'm not sure how I managed to mis-type that (and not notice I'd done it).

Comment: `C-u C-x =` runs the `what-cursor-position` function.

Answer (score 2):

I think, it can be done.

```
(defun find-face-at-point (face)
  "Find the definition of FACE.

FACE defaults to the face used on the character at point."
  (interactive (list (get-char-property (point) 'face)))
  (find-function-do-it face 'defface 'switch-to-buffer))
```

In real life some argument checking should be added to this function.

Comment: That property can be a list of faces.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I enjoyed working through your code snippet, but unfortunately it doesn't get to what I'm after.  I've edited my post explaining why in detail.