# Variable names for the nw drop down menu faces?

Tags: menu-bar, coloring

I'm trying to set up a color theme I like when using an xterm.  I'm looking through the variable names (e.g. "Font Lock Doc Face") for the theme 'deep-blue' using *Custom Theme* option.  Unfortunately, I don't see any settings that seem to correspond to the faces used when accessing the menubar at the top of the frame.

Can someone help clue me in?

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7980/how-to-determine-where-a-face-as-it-appears-on-the-screen-is-defined).  Basically, executing `list-faces-display` gives me a list of *all* variable faces.  The ones I was looking for begin with `tty-menu-*`